# How to set setuptools archive file name?

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools

When creating a source distribution using `setuptools`

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

the resulting archive file includes the version number:  `FooBar-0.0.1.tar.gz`
Is there a way to tell setup.py to create a resulting file without the version number: `FooBar.tar.gz` ?

When the archive then is published to an internal site, it is always possible to do:

```
$ pip install http://hostname/user/FooBar.tar.gz
```

The version number is still available inside the archive file. The docs allow a change of file ending/format (zip, tar, etc) but I haven't found a way for setuptools to set the file name without version number.

Outside of setuptools, it can be solved by:

```
$ mv -v dist/FooBar-* dist/FooBar.tar.gz
```

assuming there is one file `dist/FooBar-*`.

Answer (score 3):

My research shows that **you can not**.

In the [source for setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/52609e4eef7dc348dd410606440437a40cf5d167/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py#L460) you can see the code that makes the source distribution uses `self.distribution.get_fullname()`

And [that code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/52609e4eef7dc348dd410606440437a40cf5d167/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py#L1166) uses the name and version to populate the name.